# Send Binary data from a third server to Native client module

Tags: javascript, c, ajax, google-nativeclient

I receive a binary file from a third server by an Ajax GET request, then save it in a Blob and transfer the content to a Nacl Module for further process.

The js code is like this:

```
var url2 = THIRD_SERVER + 'get_gbs_params';
var args2 = {
    url: url2,
    crossDomain: true,
    crossOrigin: true,
    contentType: false,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (str){
        var bb = new Blob([str], {type: false});
        var f = new FileReader();
        f.onload = function(e){
          common.naclModule.postMessage({
            Cmd: e.target.result;
          });
        }
        f.readAsArrayBuffer(bb);
    }
$.ajax(args2);
```

and for the Native client module:

```
  pp::Var var_p_headers = dict_message.Get("Headers");      
  pp::VarArrayBuffer buffer(var_p_headers);
  uint32_t buffer_size = buffer.ByteLength();
  if (buffer_size == 0)
    return;
  unsigned char* header = static_cast<unsigned char*>(buffer.Map());
```

However, the `header` doesn't seem to be as same as the file content received from the third server. Can you spot any source of problem here in my code?

Thanks,

**UPDATE**: When I use [XMLHttpRequest](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data) instead of Jquery Ajax, it works perfectly. So the source of the problem is in the Ajax request. But why?

Comment: Jquery's ajax function is quite complex, and supports a number of different transport methods. See https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js. My guess is that there is a bug in jquery, or that there is an extra option that you need to include.